# Poisson summation formula

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an even real valued function, 
$\hat f(n)$ the $n^{\text{th}}$ Fourier coefficent of $f$ and $F$ the Fourier transform of $f$. 
I found the following problem in my lecture notes in which I have been struggling to understand for over two hours.
The poisson summation formula states
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty f(x+n)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \hat f(n)
\mathrm e^{\mathrm i2\pi nx}$$ 
Since $f$ is even and real valued it follows that we can rewrite as:
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty F(k+n)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty f(n)
\mathrm e^{\mathrm i2\pi nk}.$$
I really can't see how this follows.
Any help will be appreciated
Thank, you

Comment: Hint: what is the $n^{\text{th}}$ Fourier coefficient of $F$ ?

Comment: From your hint I realize that the formula will indeed follow if the                                 nth fourier coefficient of F(k) is f(n), so I guess it remains to figure out why this hols.

Comment: Start back from the definition of this Fourier coefficient in terms of $F(k)$ as an integral over $k$, then replace $F(k)$ by its expression, as an integral over $x$ and using Fubini, perform the integration over $k$ first.

Comment: I tried this and it is not possible to find the integral over k. I get integration of f(x)e(-2pik(x-n))dk and I cant do that.